# MONGODB_URI is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to make a Facebook chat bot following this guide: https://medium.com/@viviancpy/part-1-facebook-chatbot-with-heroku-webhook-b14090a136c7

I have no experience with node and JavaScript at all, mainly just Python. So I simply copy pasted the code from GitHub, but when I try to run it (as described in Step 4, with "yarn start") I get this error:

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

So I had a look at the code and found this:

```
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
var db = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
```

So in Python at least this would mean that the MONGODB_URI constant is undefined, but I can't figure out why. 
It might be I am missing a package (I believe it's called) or that it's a problem with me running this code on windows, or something entirely different. Have also tried to google, but either I don't understand the answer or I can't find an answer.

Comment: How are you calling this program? It sounds like `MONGODB_URI` is supposed to be an environment parameter being passed in from the caller of this program.

Comment: You have to set your environment variable MONGODB_URI or instead of define uri in code it self

Comment: Calling it from the command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Node JS Documentation on Process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

> The process.env property returns an object containing the user environment.

Read this [article](https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7) on `process.env` for better understanding. I'm going to quote from the article about what is `process.env` for TL;DR purpose

> The process.env global variable is injected by the Node at runtime for your application to use and it represents the state of the system environment your application is in when it starts. For example, if the system has a PATH variable set, this will be made accessible to you through process.env.PATH which you can use to check where binaries are located and make external calls to them if required.

That being said the problem you are facing is that your `MONGODB_URI` variable is `undefined` as your error says because you never defined it. The reason the article you followed did this is because the writer is deploying it to HEROKU and it will automatically run there. So, to solve your issue (if u want to run ur app locally)

1) Download and Install [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) (If u haven't already).

2) In your Package.JSON specifically in `"start": "node index.js"`. You can update start script to `"start": "MONGODB_URI=http://localhost:27017 node index.js"` (From Fruty's answer). (Mongo local Server starts on PORT `27017` by default). This will first set Mongo_URI to local instance of ur Mongo in your system. Then run the `Index.js` file

Answer (score 2):

`const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;`

This line means you are trying to get the mongo connection URI from the machines environment, you need to make sure you actually set it there for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```sh
MONGODB_URI=http://localhost:27017 node index.js
```

Replace index.js with your script (and uri if it need)

But I think you may use [dotnev package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to create a file called '.env' in the root directory of your project, from where you run 'heroku local'.

Using this file, heroku-cli will create an environment with the appropriate environment variables.

Step 1: Find out your actual MONGODB_URI.

Step 2: Create the .env file

Step 3: Write the line MONGODB_URI='your-actual-mongodb_uri' into the .env file

Step 4: Start your process with 'heroku local'

Your process can now access process.env.MONGODB_URI, just as if it was deployed on heroku directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called '.env.local' in your root and add the following inside it:

MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.9mmia.mongodb.net/database-name-inside-mongodb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
MONGODB_DB=database-name-inside-mongodb